# Angular2 - Assigning a control inside another component

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

Summary of the current scenario I have:

- I have a container component which has a form.
- I have a secondary component which has an input field.

The container component has a control group and would like to assign the input field inside the secondary component to this control group.

Container Component code:

```
controlInput1: Control = new Control('');
controlInput2: Control = new Control('');

containerForm: ControlGroup = new ControlGroup({
  input1: this.controlInput1,
  input2: this.controlInput2
});
```

controlInput2 or input2 is based in the secondary component which is included in the containerForm.

```
<form [ng-form-model]="containerForm">
  <input ng-control="input1" id="input1">
  <secondary-component control-id="input2"></secondary-component>
</form>
```

Secondary component code html:

```
<h1>Secondary Component!</h1>
<input ng-control="{{controlId}}" id="{{controlId}}">
```

Secondary component code TS:

```
@component({
  inputs: ['controlId']
})
export class SecondaryComponent {
  @Input() controlId;
}
```

How can I get the component to start talking with the control group in the container?

Comment: Did you figure out a way to do this? I've been trying as well, but not having any luck.

Comment: I never did, Ended up having one big file which hosts all the logic. Not really handy but I was hoping someone would of answered this by now :/